# Send array from osx to iOS on demand Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, protocols

How do I send an array through the internet from an OSX computer to an IOS device, Sorry I don't know to much about Objective C I am planning on creation an application and I haven't yet started creating it.

Thanks

Comment: What does the array contain?

Comment: How do you manage to start application without reading about the basics? you need to do some reading first then you can ask about the issues you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically want to do is use  your OS X as a server. and then download information from there. If you are new to Objective-C I would recommend you read some tutorials before you get started.

Here you can find some general iOS tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Here you can find one on NSURLSession (connecting to servers): http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Do some research before starting, or else it will probably result in a bad architected code. There also are several Stack Overflow questions with good references.

Comment: Boy has times changed..... 7 years of programming later I don't think I need this anymore xD